# Unsaved XAML file is very slow when switch to another file

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2010, xaml, silverlight-4.0

if I modify the XAML and leave it unsaved to switch to another file Visual Studio freezes for about 10 seconds before it becomes responsive again. So i expanding too much time for developing and its demotivating to me for developing.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual studio is not a XAML editor and especially if you enable the xaml UI interface view,it will get slower...So better disable the xaml UI view and edit manually. Use expression blend if you want to edit the XAML by looking at its UI.

Joy

Comment: If it's not a XAML editor, perhaps they should not allow the editing of XAML.

Answer (score 2):

The only workaround I have found is to press F5 to debug then immediately hit Ctrl + Break to cancel the build. F5 automatically saves all unsaved files, and for some reason doesn't cause the 10-20 second lock-up I get when saving normally or switching unsaved files.

It's an annoying habit to get into, but saves a little time and frustration.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and we are not alone:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/376583/ctrl-tab-between-forms-slow-with-unsaved-xaml-files

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/585430/vsip-visual-studio-builds-xaml-files-on-saving

The problem is that despite this issue was reported back in 2008, there is no workaround and MS seems not to care. :-(